# Regex for this pattern: @ or # + 1 or 2 words + : + 1 words or more + link does not work

Tags: regex

I have a pattern like this:

```
@ or # + 1 or 2 words + : + 1 words or more + link
```

So as you can see I have a sentence starting with @ or # and end with link 
like:

```
@justin Trudue:I do not [go there][1]
```

I wrote the following code to check any sentence with this pattern:

```
private static void patternFinder(String commentstr){
     String urlPattern = "#|@({1}|{2}):\\w+(https://\\w+|http://\\w+)";
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(commentstr);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }

}
```

but this does not work for example for this sentence ,should be written yes but nothing happens:

@hello sss: xxx

is there anything wrong with my regx?

Comment: Please post your actual sample strings and desired output for each string. Do not put your personal notes in these samples.

Comment: `#|@({1}|{2})` is invalid. It should be simply `[#@]`.

Comment: Try `^[#@].*(https?://[^\s]+)$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try

```
[@|#]((?:\w+\s?){1,2}):\s?((?:\w+\s?){1,})((?:http|https):\/\/.+)
```

test

```
@hello sss: xxx https://t.co/3WHshzDG7m
#hello sss: xxx another word https://t.co/3WHshzDG7m
#hello sss third: xxx another word https://t.co/3WHshzDG7m
```

Result

1. MATCH 1

   1. [1-10]  `hello sss`
   2. [12-16] `xxx`
   3. [16-39] `https://t.co/3WHshzDG7m`
2. MATCH 2

   1. [41-50] `hello sss`
   2. [52-69] `xxx another word`
   3. [69-92] `https://t.co/3WHshzDG7m`

Online demo https://regex101.com/r/zU7lP2/1

Another version if you do not want to fix the link protocol

```
[@|#]((?:\w+\s?){1,2}):\s?((?:\w+\s?){1,})((?<=\s)\w+:\/\/.+)
```

Online demo https://regex101.com/r/zU7lP2/2

Comment: Thank u, worked can you also explain this part: {1,}

Comment: Also what do u mean by fix the link protocol

Comment: Also I want the sentence to end with link or any words with # or @  like @ sss #rrrr but above pattern works with @hello sss: xxx https://t.co/3WHshzDG7m continue test which should not

Comment: `{1,}` means 1 or more of previous combintion i.e. words. Link protocol refers to http or https, may you need for ftp etc. To make it wotk with `"@ sss"` or `"# sss"` just add \s? after [@|#] , eg `"[@|#]\s?"`